# Whats the difference between "Where 'you would'/'would you' like to go"?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, questions

I was wondering if you guys could help me with this. What is the difference there in

> Where **would you** like to go?

and

> Where **you would** like to go?

Comment: The first is grammatical, the second is not. As a phrase, the second one could be grammatical in the right context (I'm asking you where you would like to go) but it all comes down to how inversion of subject and verb is used in questions.

Comment: The second one is a subordinate clause, so you hafta say _I was wondering_ before you say it.